# Make eventhandler a synonym of event-handling

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Could you add [eventhandler](/questions/tagged/eventhandler) as a synonym of [event-handling](/questions/tagged/event-handling)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[So proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/event-handling/synonyms).** If you agree with this synonym, please feel free to [vote for it](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

I'm not really sure that this should be an instant, moderator-induced change. The two tags don't refer to *exactly* the same thing, so it might be preferable to let the experts on the subject in question decide this one (which is exactly what the tag synonym proposal process is for).

Comment: event-handler is already a synonym of event-handling (and you can't add a synonym to another synonym :)